# Laravel lighthouse graphql query by relation table value

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Is it possible in Laravel lighthouse GraphQL to query by relation table values?
For example, I have defined two types.

```
type Translation {
    id: ID!
    form_group_id: Int!
    group: Group @hasOne
    translation_key: String!
    lv: String
    en: String
    ru: String
}

type Group {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    translations: [Translation]! @hasMany
}
```

and I want to query by group name.
The code below is just an example of the idea.
`translation(group.name: String! @eq): Translation @find`

I have an idea that this, can be possible with custom resolver, but is there a way using built in eloquent resolvers?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure it out? Can you provide an example? I'm trying to figure it out too. Thanks!

Comment: As I understood, there is not such functionality yet available, so I created a custom resolver that returns translations by group name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event tho this is an experimental feature, you can use [complex where conditions](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/eloquent/complex-where-conditions.html#setup). This will allow you to fetch whatever type by its relation attributes. We use it on our application, and for the use we have, this is working as expected :)